# What happens when a Worker code is updated?

Tags: android-workmanager

I have a one time (WorkManager) worker with some logic that allows it to retry (Result.retry()) when some conditions are not met. If this worker has been running and has a scheduled retry, what happens when I update the code of that worker and the user then updates the app? Would it:

1. run the old worker code?
2. continue running but run using the new worker code?
3. cancel the current job since it detects the worker code has changed?
4. ???

I'm inclined to think it would be #3 but not really sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tldr: WorkManager will run the new code (option 2).

WorkManager keep tracks of the scheduled work in a room database saving the classname of the Worker, this independently of the version of the application installed on the device and the version of the app that enqueued the request.

You may implement some migration rules to run the first time a new version is run if you need to change the default behavior.

**Note** A migration is required if you change your Worker's classname or remove it a Worker altogether. In this case you need to cancel the enqueued requests for those Workers or it will fail with a ClassNotFound Exception.

Comment: Thank you! I understand that the worker will retry on it's next schedule with the new code. Really appreciated.

Comment: You can then accept the answer if it covers your question.

Comment: But what happens if the app is not re-open after the app update that remove the worker code?

Comment: WorkManager uses JobScheduler to schedule and run workers while the application is in the background. JobScheduler will start the workers as scheduled. If your worker class is not there anymore, you're probably going to see a ClassNotFound Exception in the logs.